# Not sure how to override a random

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

```
import random
import time
import math
import sys

card_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
card_suite = ["of hearts", "of diamonds", "of clubs", "of spades", "Queen", "King", "Jack", "Ace"] #4,5,6,7
random_number = random.choice(card_numbers)
random_number2 = random.choice(card_numbers)
random_number3 = random.choice(card_numbers)
random_suite = random.choice(card_suite)

numberadd = random_number + random_number2
numberadd2 = random_number + random_number2 + random_number3

def setup():
    setupinput = raw_input("Type deal to deal the cards!")
    if setupinput == "deal":
        deal()
    elif setupinput != "deal":
        goodbye()
    else:
        print "Invalid Syntax!" 
        sys.exit(0)

def deal():
    print "Your first card is... ", random_number, random_suite
    print "Your second card is... ", random_number2, random_suite
    if numberadd >= 21:
        retry()
    else:
        thirdround()

def thirdround():
    thirdroundinput = raw_input("Would you like another card?")
    if thirdroundinput == "yes":
        print "Your next card is... ", random_number3, random_suite
        if numberadd2 >= 21:
            retry()
        else:
            print "You win! Your total was... ", numberadd2
            retry()
    elif thirdroundinput == "no":
        print "Okay... safe! Your total was... ", numberadd
    else:
        print "Invalid Syntax!"
        sys.exit(0)

def goodbye():
    print "Okay... goodbye!"
    sys.exit(0)

def retry():
    retryinput = raw_input("Would you like to try again?")
    if retryinput == "yes":
        setup()
    elif retryinput != "yes":
        goodbye()
    else:
        print "Invalid Syntax!"
        sys.exit(0)

def ifblacklist():
    if random_number or random_number2 or random_number3 == "Queen" or "King" or "Jack":
setup()
```

Brand new to coding, just finished coding this (almost done as a beginner project) and was wondering, if the random suite picks an ace, king, queen or jack, or do I make it so that it will output the number 10 (or 1 for the ace)?

Thanks

For clarification, the ifblacklist function is my attempt at making output the number 10, and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction of finishing it/rewriting

Comment: I think you should change your `suits` to an array of just the names: `[ 'hearts', 'spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs']`. Also, you should use `ranks = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']`. Get a random number from 0-3 for the suits and 0-13 for the ranks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. The code seems incomplete. For example, where do you call `ifblacklist()`? Do you have `main()` method or something similar?

Comment: Oops, I mean 0-12 (Had a 1 in there...) Referencing an object by an index is a lot more efficient and abstract than comparing string literals.

Comment: What is the desired output? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @howaboutNO The desired output is currently getting two cards, and if you want, a third. But I want to know that if one of those cards is a jack, king or queen, how would I go about making sure that the number for those is a 10.

Comment: @Marcin For clarification, the ifblacklist function is my attempt at making output the number 10, and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction of finishing it/rewriting. No main method - I'm new and still learning and used many other methonds instead of 1 main

Comment: Either make each rank an `object` and assign each a name and a face-value *or* use a function that contains a `switch` which returns the value, given a name. Very simple actually.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl ahaha, thanks for your help! I'm still learning so not to simple :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, all `else` blocks like this;

```
retryinput = raw_input("Would you like to try again?")
    if retryinput == "yes":
        setup()
    elif retryinput != "yes":
        goodbye()
    else:
        print "Invalid Syntax!"
        sys.exit(0)
```

Are unnecessary. Because your program never process that `else` , since `elif retryinput != "yes":` comprise all situations. So you should delete that else blocks they are useless or
you should change them like;

```
retryinput = raw_input("Would you like to try again?")
    if retryinput == "yes":
        setup()
    elif retryinput == "no":
        goodbye()
    else:
        print "Invalid Syntax!"
        sys.exit(0)
```

Second, this function

```
def ifblacklist():
   if random_number or random_number2 or random_number3 == "Queen" or "King" or "Jack":
setup()
```

Should be;

```
if random_number=="Queen" or random_number2=="King" or random_number3=="Jack":
    do something
```

Otherwise it will be always `True`, you should write all conditions/equalitions. How would you go about making sure that the number for those is a 10;

You can do that like; make a dict and put key/values like this;

```
mydict={"Queen":10,"King":10...}
```

Then search your card in this dict, and sum their values.